# Using Torricelli's Law

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The problem reads: At time t=0 the bottom plug (at the vertex) of a full conical tank of water 16 ft high is removed. After 1 hour, the water in the tank is 9 ft deep. When will the tank be empty?

Ok so I know the law is $A(y)\frac{dy}{dt}=-ac\sqrt{2gy}$, where c=0.6 since it's water

So I know that $A(y)=\pi R^2 $, R is the radisu of where the water is, $a=\pi r^2$, where small r is the radius of the plug and g=32.

Honestly I find that the problem is finding a relation between R and y, I can't find a relation with cones.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps. Use the fact that for a cone $V = \frac{1}{3} \pi R^{2} y$. Then $\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{1}{3} \pi R^{2}$. From Torricelli's Law $ \frac{1}{3} \pi R^{2} \frac{dy}{dt} = -ac \sqrt{2gy}$. This is variables separable. You can take it from there. Note we are given the height of the fluid at two points, that is because we are not given the radius of the small hole, therefore one data point is to take care of the constant of integration, and the other to rid ourselves of the unknown radius of the hole. Best of luck. 
EDIT: Having gone through the calculation, I found the answer to be t = 2. We have $\frac{1}{3} \pi r^{2} \frac{dy}{dt} = -ac\sqrt{2gy} \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{y} = kt.$ Where $k$ is the bunch of constants we had. Then integrating $2(\sqrt{y} - \sqrt{y(0)}) = kt$. Hence $y(0) = 16$ and we know at $t = 1$ we have $ y = 9$, therefore $k = 2(3-4) = -2$. Then if we set $y = 0$, we obtain $t = 4$ as claimed.

Comment: Doesn't R depend on y though, so you can't integrate like that?

Comment: Because the way I understand it is that the Area on the left is the circle inside the cone, not the surface area of the cylinder

Comment: You're right. My bad. So it's a cone, and the general equation of an inverted cone is $r=y$ where $y$ is taken to be the vertical height of the cone (the coordinate along the symmetry axis of the cone), therefore we see that the volume is $\frac{1}{3} \pi y^{3}$. Then you proceed as before. Sorry again.

Comment: No problem at all!  I never know that the radius was inverted like that, thanks!